# windows 10 uwp support .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, win-universal-app, uwp

I have to develop a universal Windows 10 application that uses some old code, but there are some elements that are not supported within the UWP. Is there any website where I can find a list of namespaces/functions et cetera that are not supported within the Universal Windows Platform?

For example, the System.Drawing namespace is not supported within the platform. System.Windows.Media, however, is.

I don't know if I am making myself clear enough. If not, I'll try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the full .net framework available to you in UWP apps.  Here is a link to the API reference for UWP apps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/bg124285.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any website where I can find a list of namespaces/functions et cetera that are not supported within the Universal Windows Platform?

See **[Windows API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx)** to check available APIs in WINRT/UWP apps.

Windows Runtime apps and Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps can use a subset of the Win32 and COM APIs, see **[Win32 and COM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx)**